# How to log user in after successful registration using Ajax ? Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to use a Modal registration box using Ajax. It works but how can I log user in as well ?

This is the overloaded `register` function in RegisterController.php:

```
 /**
 * Handle a registration request for the application (overloaded).
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $this->create($request->all());

    return response()->json();
}
```

This is the standard function that ships with Laravel and logs user in upon registration.

```
/**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

And this is the AJAX call:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#formRegister', function(e) {  
            e.preventDefault();

            $('input+small').text('');
            $('input').parent().removeClass('has-error');

            $.ajax({
                method: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json"
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('.alert-success').removeClass('hidden');
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data.responseJSON, function (key, value) {
                    var input = '#formRegister input[name=' + key + ']';
                    $(input + '+small').text(value);
                    $(input).parent().addClass('has-error');
                });
            });
        });
```

How can I log user in and redirect to `/home`

Comment: You are already returning empty json response using `return response()->json();`

Comment: Registration is successful but how can I log user in and redirect to redirectPath()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `success` in AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
     method: $(this).attr('method'),
     url: $(this).attr('action'),
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     dataType: "json",

     //add success option with following callback function
     success: function(response) {

         //(optional) check for response

         window.location.href = '/home' //your desired url
     }
});
```

**PS**: as it'll redirect `.done` after AJAX request will not be performed.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I also added: $this->guard()->login($this->create($request->all())); to log user before the refresh. I'm new to AJAX so if you could remove the -1. thnx!